# How to count distinct numbers in a range greater than a value

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm working on M/M/1/k simulation in excel.

I have a problem to count distinct values greater than a specific value.

For example, I have two column with values `C={1;2;3;4;5}`, `D={4;5;5;5;6}`

Here I want to count somehow `COUNTIF(D1:D5,">"&C4)`, the answer would be 2 because I don't want to count repeated numbers (I used here `COUNTIF` just for reference).

Comment: But there is only one value in column **D** greater than **5** ??

Answer (score 1):

Use the following formula, C4 is the cell which you want to compare with the values D1:D5, I used your example to count the number of unique values in column D greater than C4, by using a multiplication to have an array and remove the duplicates and count it only once, it is an array formula, press **Ctrl + Shift + Enter**  after you enter it.
`=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(D1:D5>C4,(D1:D5>C4)*D1:D5,""),IF(D1:D5>C4,(D1:D5>C4)*D1:D5,""))>0,1))`

Comment: Need a few $'s ... `$D$1:$D$5`

Comment: Kashif can modify the references as needed

Answer (score 0):

Here's one method ...

[image]

... where "Unique Data2" contains the array formula ...

```
{=IFERROR(INDEX($D$2:$D$6,MATCH(0,COUNTIF($E$1:$E1,$D$2:$D$6),0)),"")}
```

... and "No Data2 > Data1" contains your CountIf formula ...

```
=COUNTIF($E$2:$E$6,">"&C2)
```